# Constructor argument is undefined?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a constructor with getter and setters which seem to work fine for all of my attributes except when I call it in my `main` argument.

When I get to this line of code:

```java
flip firstFlip = new flip("Heads");
flip secondFlop = new flip("Tails");
```

Then I get the following error in my console:

> The constructor flip(String) is undefined
> The constructor flip(String) is undefined

Perhaps I have missed something here?

```java
public class flip {
    private String head;
    private String tails;

    public flip() {
    }

    public flip(String head, String tails) {
        super();
        this.head = head;
        this.tails = tails;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(String head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public String getTails() {
        return tails;
    }

    public void setTails(String tails) {
        this.tails = tails;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flip firstFlip = new flip("Heads");
        flip secondFlop = new flip("Tails");

        System.out.println("The first flip is a:" + firstFlip.getHead());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't have a constructor which takes 1 argument.

Comment: You have two constructors: one takes no args, the other takes two args. You are trying to call a constructor with one arg.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but, how is this class supposed to work?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you, I better understand this now

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've just started on working with constructors, so I'm trying to get used to the arguments. Though, I aim on trying to create a class that returns either heads or tails when a random number is generated between two numbers.

Comment: @Stackbeans ok, got it :)

Comment: @Stackbeans You do not inherit your class from another class, so there is no need to call the constructor of superclass  inside your class. The constructor of `Object` class  will be called implicitly in any case. So, you don't need to call `super()` in your case. This only adds garbage to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined because there is no constructor of the class that accepts 1 argument.

You're missing a second parameter.

```
flip firstFlip = new flip("Heads",  tails);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    package flipapp;
    
    
    public class Flip {
        private String head;
        private String tails;
        public Flip(String head, String tails) {
            super();
            this.head = head;
            this.tails = tails;
        }
        public String getHead() {
            return head;
        }
        public void setHead(String head) {
            this.head = head;
        }
        public String getTails() {
            return tails;
        }
        public void setTails(String tails) {
            this.tails = tails;
        }
        
    }

package flipapp;

public class TestFlipApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flip flip1 = new Flip("head", "tails");

    System.out.println("The first flip is a: "+flip1.getHead());
    System.out.println("The second flip is a: "+flip1.getTails());


}
}
```

just try creating an other class for main method it will work